# Changes in compact layout only occasionally show in highlights panel

Tags: lightning, compact-layout, highlights-panel

I am having problems changing the fields that are shown in the Lightning highlights panel. In theory, these fields are the first seven that are assigned via the compact page layout.

In practice however, this turns out to be problematic. Only occasionally are my changes reflected in the highlights panel. The fields that are shown in the highlights panel in 'Edit Page' always match the fields that are selected in the compact page layout.

But viewing a Lead or Account itself, which should use the changed highlights panel/compact layout, gives me mixed results. Sometimes I see the changes, sometimes I don't. Ctrl-F5, restarting the browser, using a different browser, ... inconsistent results.

I am considering filing a case with Salesforce Support, but it's hard to make a 100% reproducible scenario.

Record types are not the issue, neither is field accessibility. I get this with both Leads and Accounts. Anyone recognizing these problems and having found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround seems to be to change user language. Our org supports four user languages, and switching between them just after a compact layout change seems to be a way of getting Lightning to use the most recent updates.